# Qt slots and inheritance: why is my program trying to connect to the parent instead of the child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, qt4, signals-slots

In a Qt program, I have a `QWidget` class that is the superclass of another class declared so:

```cpp
class Renderer : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ....
}

class A : public Renderer
{ .... }
```

Now I have a slot for class A that is not present in `Renderer`, but when I try to run the program, it fails to make connections to class A:

```
Object::connect: <sender name: 'push_button'>
Object::connect: <receiver name: 'A'>
Object::connect: No such slot Renderer::loadDialog() in <file path>
```

Why is it trying to connect to Renderer and not A? Am I supposed to have a slot in Renderer of the same name?

Thanks

edit:

here's the declaration of the slot in A:

```cpp
public slots:
    void loadDialog();
```

and as for the connections, I'm relying on Qt Creator mostly, but here's what was in the ui_windows.h file:

```cpp
QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), A, SLOT(loadDialog()));
```

Hope that clears things up a bit :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you show the code where you connect the signal and slot? Maybe it would also be helpful to see the slot declaration in class A.

EDIT:

Try to add Q_OBJECT macro in subclass A. Another thing could be that the slot is not virtual (but according to what I read that shouldn't make a difference).

These are just guesses, the code you posted looks ok for me. I don't have Qt available on that computer so I can't try it out :(.

Comment: Whenever you want to declare new signals/slots to your subclass, you have to use Q_OBJECT macro

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in that class A did not have the Q_OBJECT declaration, so the signals and slots do not work with it. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Didn't see above answer before submitting my own answer.